# Using a regex in Perl, how do I find the first occurrence of any letter?

Tags: regex, perl

I am stumped; I've tried a few things so far but what I am trying to extract is the first letter in a Perl string.

I have for example:

```
10emV
```

I want to use a regex to extract the first letter, which in this case would be `e`.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply search for `\p{L}`, or `[a-zA-z]` for ASCII letters. The first match is the first letter.

If you want to match the start of the string (for some reason), you can also use `\A\P{L}*\p{L}`, or `\A[^a-zA-z]*[a-zA-z]`.

See also: [Perl regular expressions tutorial - More on characters, strings, and character classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#More-on-characters,-strings,-and-character-classes)

Comment: Needless to say, it all depends on what "letter" means. Also: This is my 1000th answer on stack overflow...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $string =~ m/([[:alpha:]])/ ) {
    print $1, $/;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, what does the `$/` do?

Comment: Oh, that's the Perl special variable that holds the input record separator (usually '\n').  I probably should have typed, 'print "$1\n";'  That would have been clearer.

Answer (score -1):

```
my $let = $1 if '10emV' =~ m/([a-z]+?)/g;
print $let;
```

Comment: Don't declare lexical variables in conditionals. Which `$let` do you think that is if the condition returns false? :)

Comment: @brian d foy, true enough! my inattention :(